# how to filter the results based on web property

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am displaying the results using REST API from list using following code. have one status columns in list and have one status webproperty in web part properties with values New/Approve/Reject but i have to display the results based on selected value from drop-down in web properties. Here is my function to display results.

```
function getResults() {

 var requestUri = appweburl "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/Lists/getByTitle('listName')/items?&@target='" + hostweburl + "'";

    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl.toLowerCase());

    executor.executeAsync({
        url: requestUri,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: successHandler,
        error: errorHandler
    });
}
```

What would be the convenient wayt to change the requestUri so i can filter results based on one of three values from drop down .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply filter in the `onchange` of your drop-down. If your column name is `Status`, then it should look like

```
$filter=Status eq "Selected value from drop-down"
```

## Example

I guess your *HTML* is

```
<select name="" id="filter" onchange="applyFilter()">
  <option value="New">New</option>
  <option value="Approve">Approve</option>
  <option value="Reject">Reject</option>
</select>
```

No in the *JS* code, add following

```
function applyFilter(){
    var selectedFilter = document.querySelector("#filter").value;
    var requestUri = appweburl "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/Lists/getByTitle('listName')/items?$filter=status eq '"+selectedFilter+"'&@target='" + hostweburl + "'";
    getResults(requestUri);
  }

function getResults(requestUri) {

    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl.toLowerCase());

    executor.executeAsync({
        url: requestUri,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: successHandler,
        error: errorHandler
    });
}
```

To find more about $filter, have a look [CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Comment: I have tried above but its not working .Not getting results .

Comment: Can you update your question with what you have tried?

Comment: i have tried with the following query as u mentioned in your answer .iam getting value from dropdown but it dont display results .   var requestUri = appweburl "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/Lists/getByTitle('listName')/items?$filter=status eq '"+selectedFilter+"'&@target='" + hostweburl + "'";

Comment: what about the html? Is it same as mine?

Comment: no i have dropdown in app part propery and iam getting value from webpart property by usingas follows  selectedFilter = getQueryStringParameter("Status");